# JSP:useBean class attribute "javaPackage.java class" is invalid

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, javabeans

Im trying to do this tutorial: http://www.javatpoint.com/registration-form-in-jsp. However as I'm trying to add some users to my database I get this error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /register/newAccountCreated.jsp (line: 7, column: 0) The value for the useBean class attribute bean.AppUser is invalid.
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:149)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1242)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$UseBean.accept(Node.java:1196)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2392)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2444)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2450)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:474)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2392)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3529)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:251)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Checking upon this error someone pointed out that i could be missing the **jsp:setProperty** but it's not the case. My jsp (to where my form points to) looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<%@page import="bean.RegisterUser"%>  
<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="bean.AppUser" />  

<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="obj"/> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>


<%  
int status=RegisterUser.register(obj);  
if(status>0)  
out.print("You Were successfully registered");  

%>  
</body>
</html>
```

My 
My appUser class snippet:

```
package bean;
public class AppUser {

    private String userName;
    private String userPass;
    private boolean userActive;
    private String userSignInDate;

    public AppUser(String pUserName, String pUserPass){
        this.userActive = true;
        this.userName = pUserName;
        this.userPass = pUserPass;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getUserPass() {
        return userPass;
    }
    public void setUserPass(String userPass) {
        this.userPass = userPass;
    }
    public boolean isUserActive() {
        return userActive;
    }
    public void setUserActive(boolean userActive) {
        this.userActive = userActive;
    }
    public String getUserSignInDate() {
        return userSignInDate;
    }
    public void setUserSignInDate(String userSignInDate) {
        this.userSignInDate = userSignInDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you deploying your app on the server?

Comment: run as->run on server-> there i would pick the tomcat server... now im guessing... i have to copy my project into the tomcat directory right? @RaviThapliyal I thought that what i was doing was deploying my project into the tomcat....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you haven't provided a *default* constructor to your `bean.AppUser` class. Anytime, you provide a *class* with an explicit constructor, the compiler no longer provides the *default no-argument* constructor for it which it does if one doesn't declare any constructors.

The JSP standard actions like `<jsp:useBean>` are named so because they work with JavaBeans only. A *JavaBean* has to have a *zero-argument constructor*, and must allow access to its properties using getter and setter methods.

Comment: It did work! thanks a lot!, now i have and issue with this stament
`PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into appuser values(?,?)");  ` it doesn't throw an error o anything, it just doesn't go throught

Comment: Please, update your question with the relevant code and the exception stacktrace and let me know down here. I'll take a look again.